# How to disable auto scroll to the top during click event

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Just like in the title - **how do I disable the auto scroll during the `click` `eventListener`?**
I'm creating a simple app to help me track which shows I have watched or I am watching at this moment and I have implemented the score module (I'm creating a new with default score set to 0 and by clicking on it I'm firing up an `eventListener` to `display:block` a hidden HTML select list):

```
setScore(){
    const score = document.getElementById(`user-score-${this.id}`);
    const scoreList = document.getElementById(`score-list-${this.id}`);
    score.addEventListener('click', () => {
        score.style.display = "none";
        scoreList.style.display="block";
        scoreList.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            score.textContent = e.target.value;
            this.updateScore(this.id, e.target.value);
            score.style.display="block";
            scoreList.style.display="none";
        })
    })
}
```

Unfortunately when I'm clicking on said score it automatically scrolls to the top of the whole page.
So when the show is placed far at the bottom I can't really set its score without needing to find it again, this time with `select` list shown.

I really don't know how to fix that nor I was able to find the answer on the web.
I would really appreciate any insights on this topic.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: if you have `href="#"` try changing it to `href="javascript::"`

Comment: Oh my god, it just worked... Thank you so much!

Comment: glad I could help.